# 555 timer square wave LED flasher

Tags: led, 555, npn

Will this circuit work for the purpose of making a high voltage LED flash on and off at 10kHz?

I have a NPN transistor to turn the LED on and off. The pad is where the LED will be soldered into as they are attached with wires.[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, your frequency calculation is way off for 10kHz.

That will give you closer to 7Hz, more than 1000x slower. You can reducer the capacitor to about 7nF (7000pF) to get closer to 10kHz. For the bipolar 555 in particular it's important to bypass the supply. I show 100uF electrolytic in parallel with 100nF ceramic or film, but even a 10uF electrolytic will be better than nothing.

[image]
This is the updated version
[image]

Comment: Oh really, oooops. What values would I need? I guess I did a wrong calculation somewhere.

Comment: The resistor values are okay, reduce the capacitor to more like 7nF (7000pF). Also 100nF in parallel with 100uF electrolytic across the power rails.

Comment: Thank for the feedback, yes I did realise the value of C was too large. Would you mind sketching on the schematic the changes needed please. Thank you Spehro.  And the NPN would work this way to turn LED on and off?

Comment: Thank you very much and it is all very clear. I will show you my PCB once it is constructed on easyEDA.

Comment: Spehro, while you are at correcting errors , delete R13 and Q1 which are redundant, since OUT can drive ±200  mA and R14 suggests we do not expect much current but can't be sure what LED current and Vcc is being used.,  but adding 100uF to Vcc is overkill

Comment: Voltage drop on those old bipolar 555s is a volt or two when sourcing so there might be other changes after more questions. Sinking would be better. I think that's getting outside of the scope of the question. 100uF or 47uF is my standard depending on voltage because they're hardly bigger or more expensive than 10uF for 16V or 25V rating. The switching surge is typically around 400mA which is pretty significant but even 10uF || 10nF  would keep it reasonably low (<10mV). CMOS types are significantly better.

Comment: Does this look better? I also changed the 555 IC. What frequency should this give now? What is the equations for calculations?